# Military member asks me if she can have money wired into my bank account but needs my social security number and bank routing number

Tags: banking, fraud, scams

I was recently talking to someone online and she said that she was in the Army and then she went on to tell me that she had a lump sum of 45,000$ co.i g to her but she needed my bank account routing number, asked for my social security number, and then told me that she was going to have the Army wire me the money into my account now my question;

Is this a scam?

Comment: If anyone can please answer my question because I dont know what to do because I feel bad in a way and she said she wont do me wrong but I also know there are alot of scams out there so is this a scam my situation that is and I never met her before and she wants to wire money into my account any suggestions

Comment: Did you ever stop to think why somebody, whom you don''t know at all, wants to give you $45000 ?

Comment: Jason - this is 100% certainly a scam. See the other Q&A that's a duplicate of your question.

Comment: Suggested edit: replace "military member" with "someone". Doesn't matter who they clam to be. –

Answer (score 15):

This is almost surely a scam.  Among other things:

- Why would a stranger wire that type of money into your account if she doesn't know you?
- Assuming that she was going to wire you money, she would NOT need your SSN to do it.

Comment: The only flaw with this answer is the word "Almost"

Answer (score 8):

You don't say WHY she wants to give you money. Your paragraph appears to be the very definition of a scam. Run from her.

Comment: I believe you mean "her".